# On demand Publishing?

Tags: ros, msg-subscriber, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS kinetic with Yumi package from KTH. I am getting some points from the camera and do some processing and send the coordinates back to the robot arms to move. What I'm doing is letting the camera input and processing system on a node (publisher) to publish the coordinates and the control and move of the robot one (subscriber) on another node. The problem is that the camera publish sequence of coordinates to the robot.
My question is that how can I publish the first message only and then wait till demand or flag to publish the second message and so on?

Thank you in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281174/on-demand-publishing?/) by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using a publisher and subscriber you could use a [service and client](http://wiki.ros.org/Services).

The camera input and processing would be in the service, and the client would request the coordinate whenever it needs it.

Here is a service/client tutorial for [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) or here is one for [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4